# SN Computer Science Journal 2-column Latex Template

Tags: templates, journal, springer

Where can I find the template for the 2-column SN Computer Science Journal. I download the one from: https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

I also changed it to the two column version but it doesn't look like the published articles on the journal, check this one as an example:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s42979-022-01507-0.pdf?pdf=button

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use this for for sending something to SN Journal? If so, do not change anything as they may use their own version of the package.

Comment: The published version you link to is not set with tex, it is not unusual for journals to accept latex submissions but convert in-house. Authors just worry about the content, the publisher controls the layout.

Comment: Thanks, Peter and David. I'm keeping the same template to submit the article.